# do lower precedence operators associate non-associative higher precedence operators?

Tags: php, operators

">=" and "==" are non-associative operators and when they are next to each other, they get evaluated by precedence:

```
2 >= 3 == 3
```

it's like:

```
(2 >= 3) == 3 // ">=" have higher precedence over "=="
```

but if there is an associative operator in the mix, even lower precedence operator, it get evaluated acording to the associative operator:

```
var_dump($a = 2 >= $b = 3 == 3); // bool(true)
var_dump(2 >= 3 == 3); // bool(false)
```

it's ilke:

```
var_dump($a = 2 >= ($b = 3 == 3));
var_dump((2 >= 3) == 3);
```

did i understood it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP parses always only the defined ways. And giving variable assignments a higher (implicit) precedence is necessary as on the left of an assignment **must** be a variable. It's impossible to parse as `($a = 2 >= $b) = 3 == 3`. It doesn't depend on the associativity.

Look at this example; the `&` operator is associative (and the `=>` isn't).

```
$b = 2;
$a = 2 >= $b & 2;
```

In this case it is left to right. Like:

```
var_dump($a = ((2 >= $b) & 2)); // int (0)
var_dump($a = 2 >= $b & 2); // int (0)
```

Compare to:

```
var_dump($a = (2 >= ($b & 2))); // bool (true)
```